# Dimension of the subspace $\{ p(B) : p \text{ is a polynomial with real coefficients}\}$ where $B$ is a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $$W= \{ p(B) : p \text{ is a polynomial with real coefficients}\},$$ where $$
B=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&1\\
1&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

What of the following inequalities is satisfied by the dimension of the vector space $W$?

1. $4 \leq d \leq 6$;
2. $6 \leq d \leq 9$;
3. $3 \leq d \leq 8$;
4. $3 \leq d \leq 4$.

The following is how I have proceeded
Here,
$$B^2=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

$$B^3=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&1\\
0&1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
And, $B^4=B$, $B^5=B^2$ and so on.

Hence, we can say that the **degree** of p(B) $\le$ 3.

Since every power of $B$ greater than $3$ can be written as a power of $B$ less than or equal to $3$, every polynomial in $B$ can be reduced to $P+ QB+ RB^2+ SB^3$.  That is, every such polynomial can be identified with the quadruple of numbers $(P, Q, R, S)$.  So, what is the dimension of this space? How do I proceed now?

Comment: $B^2$ and $B^3$ are wrong. Furthermore you should have realized this as is impossible for any matrix to have a power $A^{n+1}=A$ if $A^n \neq I$ because $AA^{n} = A^{n+1}$ there is no other value for $A^n$ to take than $I$.

Answer (score 3):

The characteristic polynomial of $B$ can be calculated to be $$1-t^3 = -(t-1)\left(t - \frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}2\right)\left(t - \frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}2\right)$$

so $B$ has three distinct eigenvalues. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $B$ is $m_B(x) = x^3-1$.

This implies that the set $\{I, B, B^2\}$ is linearly independent (otherwise there would exist a nonzero polynomial of degree $\le 2$ annihilating $B$).

On the other hand, for every $p \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ there exists unique $q, r \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ such that $p = m_B q + r$ and $\deg r < \deg m_A = 3$.

Now we have $p(B) = m_A(B)q(B) + r(B) = r(B)$ so we see that every element of $W$ can be expressed as $r(B)$ with $\deg r \le 2$.

Therefore $\{I, B, B^2\}$ is a basis for $W$ so $\dim W = 3$.